# Can we access same BLE Mesh network from one phone to other

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52, mesh-network

I'm working on a BLE Mesh project in which I have successfully implemented the BLE Mesh node provisioning and controlling. Now I want to control the same network with another phone. How to export and import the same network and data to another phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the same network from other phone we needs to export and import the data from one phone to other, to do so If you are using the [nRF Mesh app](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Mesh-Library) just go to 'Setting Tab', At upper right corner there is 3 dots, click on it and there you can see the mesh network import/ export.
See: [Link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/75267/how-to-control-same-mesh-network-by-different-mobiles-if-login-via-same-user)